# C# Search for term on a text file and put it in textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, streamreader

I've got one .properties file with this content:

```
# Credenciais da Base de Dados

 host_bd= localshot
#
user_bd=root
#
pass_bd=
#
```

So what I want is to read this file, and pass (for example) "localhost" to one textbox.

I know I have to search for "host_bd=" and read all line, but how can I pass just the "localhost" to the textbox ?

Edit: What I've tried so far

I can read the entire file and put the content in a textbox (just use streamreader for read all file).

Also have one function that I use for save the textbox values to the txt file, but this function write all file again and substitutes the search term for the replace term (searchterm+somevalue), I've tried to change this function for my purpose but no luck so far...

Comment: use reg expressions? string.split?

Comment: Just a couple of things to check out: `File.ReadAllText`, regular expressions to look for correct line and extract correct part of line and then `textBox.Text = stringContainingLocalhost;`

Comment: @meilke reading all is dangerous as the file may be larger than the available memory. Instead read one line at a time.

Comment: Why not just put 'localhost' in the text box?  Or whatever you were searching for?

Comment: Garry because host_bd value could be changed in the application..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string line = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Where(l =>l.Trim().StartsWith("host_bd")).FirstOrDefault();
string value = line.Split('=')[1].Trim();
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly :) Just one "error", it's "StartsWith" and not "StartWith", you saved my day !

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\s*host_bd\s*=\s*(?<host_bd>.*)\s*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);

string fileContent = File.ReadAllText(".properties");

Match m = regex.Match(fileContent);

if (m.Success)
{
    myTextBox.Text = m.Groups["host_bd"].Value;
}
else
{
    myTextBox.Text = "unknown";
}
```

Comment: thank you Benoit I appreciate your answer. Works great, shows me the "#" instead of the "unknown" but no problem at all with that, but the Damith answer seems more "light" and works fine. But useful answer anyway, thanks !